# Fast method to cut/shred glue stick into small pieces

Tags: cutting

Tried cutting a glue stick into small pieces using a normal scissor and took about 10 mins or so.

Is it possible to cut or shred glue stick into small pieces much faster, say 2 min per stick?

(The reason is that the shredded glue stick is going to be used in a craft work.)

Comment: For like a hot glue gun, or one of the kid-safe sticks that twist out of the tube?

Comment: What kind of glue stick again?  There are a lot of answers that seem to assume a hot glue stick.

Comment: How small do you want the pieces? Like "grated" small or just in chunks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a sharp knife and cut chips at one end, as if sharpening a pencil. Keep cutting until you get the needed quota :)

If a specific (different) shape of the pieces is needed, then we need more details.

Comment: "As if sharpening a pencil" - depending on how thick the gluestick is, perhaps an *actual* pencil sharpener would be viable?  Especially if OP can use an electric one to reduce effort even further!

Comment: It depends on the technology of the __actual__ pencil sharpener. In some cases, they are actually able to create sheets instead of chips.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting the glue stick in a freezer and cutting/shaving it with a knife after it cools down somewhat. The cold glue won't deform or stick to the blade so readily so you'll have a slightly easier time managing the pieces.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to grab Stefan's answer of bundling the stick, but also suggest that a coarse cheese grater would give consistent results and reasonably good production. Keep your fingers clear and slice away. It may also be useful to chill the glue sticks, perhaps freeze them to reduce the melting caused by friction.

Comment: Would a well made kitchen food processor cut these?

Comment: That's a great idea. There are plenty of videos on YouTube under "will it blend?" Items much tougher than glue sticks are involved.

Comment: I was also thinking coffee grinder. Coffee beans would be about the same hardness?

Comment: glue sticks can be marked by one's fingernail, which implies softness. The heat of friction would probably melt the glue.

Comment: I’d say you’re right about hardness. Good point.

Answer (score 3):

Place them in the freezer for several minutes, then use a mandolin-style vegetable slicer.  You can get very consistent slices that way.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are cutting dozens, I'd wrap a bunch in tape where you are not cutting, and then cut them with a heated blade/knife. Alternatively a hacksaw or serrated breadknife.

Update: Sorry misread the post: I though they wanted short glue sticks, not shredded, so my idea is not that great!